# Android New Image has strange numbers on the end of the file name

Tags: android

I'm writing a camera2 app in android and when I try to save the image, something adds extra numbers on the end of the filename before the '.jpg'

I have a feeling it's because of the `createTempFile()` method, but here's my code:

```
File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    ++image_id;
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(new Date());
    String subFolder = "";
    if(pref_session_unique_gallery.equals("yes")){
        if(event_name != null){
            subFolder = event_name;
        } else {
            subFolder = timestamp;
        }
    } else {
        subFolder = "_GEN";
    }
    if(event_name == null){
        imageFileName = "CPB_"+timestamp+"-"+image_id;
    } else {
        imageFileName = "CPB_"+event_name+"_"+timestamp+"-"+image_id;
    }
    imageStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "CPB" + File.separator + subFolder;
    imageFinalFileName = imageFileName;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), imageStorageDirectory + "/" + imageFileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File storageDirectory = new File(imageStorageDirectory);
    storageDirectory.mkdir();
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDirectory);
    return image;
}
```

When I read the toast it gives me the correct path and filename that I am expecting, but when I look in my folder view, the picture has a lot of extra numbers on it.

For example, the picture name should be `CPB_20160120-1.jpg` but it currently reads `CPB_20160120-1484291604.jpg` If it makes a difference, the file was saved at `6:37 PM`

two more examples:

should be: `CPB_20160120-2.jpg`
is: `CPB_20160120-22140921986.jpg`

should be: `CPB_20160120-3.jpg`
is: `CPB_20160120-3-965716644.jpg`

Not sure where those extra numbers are coming from when the file saves...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those random numbers are explicitly generated by `createTempFile()`, as seen in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/java/io/File.java#File.createTempFile%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.io.File%29).

You probably don't want to use temporary files anyway, thus I'd recommend to create normal files:

```
File image = new File(storageDirectory, imageFileName + ".jpg");
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this, though it didn't save the file to the location I've tried to specify.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ntgCleaner Where does it get saved then? Does `image.getAbsolutePath()` output the path you'd expect?

Comment: Great question!  The folder gets created, but the file does not save in that location. Does it have to do with the fact that I'm not saving it in the app folder, but mainly the user root of the app

Comment: @ntgCleaner Do all folders exist? I just saw that you are using `mkdir()` instead of `mkdirs()`

Comment: It only makes a single folder that is there. I can confirm by looking in the file directory

Comment: For some reason, this is working now...  Ha, code gremlins.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According implementation of used method new file is created with extra random integer `new File(tmpDirFile, prefix + Math.randomIntInternal() + suffix)`

```
public static File createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)
            throws IOException {
        // Force a prefix null check first
        if (prefix.length() < 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("prefix must be at least 3 characters");
        }
        if (suffix == null) {
            suffix = ".tmp";
        }
        File tmpDirFile = directory;
        if (tmpDirFile == null) {
            String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir", ".");
            tmpDirFile = new File(tmpDir);
        }
        File result;
        do {
            result = new File(tmpDirFile, prefix + Math.randomIntInternal() + suffix);
        } while (!result.createNewFile());
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is `Math.randomIntInternal()` ?

Comment: it's some internal method of used class

Comment: I can't find this method in a Math.java implementation :/

Comment: @dit u can use Random.nextInt() instead http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/java/io/File.java#1005